# How to make UITableView sections according to Month - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have an array of objects that contain `NSDate` property in them. And I'm populating them successfully in a `UITableView`.

I want to distribute them (the objects) in `UITableView` sections according to their month.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to group them by months, then return number of sections.

Answer (score 1):

Please review this code once.It may help you.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dictArrData; //declare dictionary global

-(void)createHederAndCellArray
{
    dictArrData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(int i=0;i<arrHistory.count;i++)
    {
       yourObject *pastorders=[arrHistory objectAtIndex:i];
       if([dictArrData objectForKey:pastorders.paymentDate])
       {
          NSMutableArray *arrTemp=[dictArrData objectForKey:pastorders.paymentDate];
          [arrTemp addObject:pastorders];
          [dictArrData setObject: arrTemp forKey:pastorders.paymentDate];
       }
       else
       {
          NSMutableArray * arrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
          [arrTemp  addObject:pastorders];
         [dictArrData setObject: arrTemp forKey:pastorders.paymentDate];
       }
   }
   NSLog(@“check dictionary %@",[dictArrData description]);
}
```

**[self createHederAndCellArray];** ----> this method you need to call after adding data in your array and than set code in tableview as below.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [dictArrData allKeys].count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    NSArray *allValues=(NSArray*)[dictArrData objectForKey:[[dictArrData allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]];
   return [allValues count];
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 22, tableView.frame.size.width,15)];
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,25)];

  [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
  label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
  NSString *sectionTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[[dictArrData allKeys]  objectAtIndex:section]];
  NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
  NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sectionTitle];
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = @“MMM";
  NSString *sectionTitle =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"    %@",     [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
  [view addSubview:imgvw];
  [view addSubview:label];
  [label setText:sectionTitle];
  return view;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

    yourcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@“yourcellidentifier” forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[yourcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"yourcellidentifier"];
   }
   @try
   {
        //keyArr=[self sortKeyAccordingTodate];
        NSArray *allValues=[dictArrData objectForKey:[[dictArrData allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        if(allValues.count >0 )
        {
            yourObject *pastorder=[allValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.lblProductname.text=pastorder.itemName;
        }
   }    
   @catch (NSException *exception) {
      NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.description);
   }
    return cell;
}

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 25;
}
```

To sort according to date than you need to sort dictionary keys.

```
  -(NSArray *)sortKeyAccordingTodate
  { 
        NSArray* sorted  = [[dictArrData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
                   {
                       NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                       dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                       NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
                       NSDate *date1  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];

                       if (date > date1) {
                           return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                       }
                       if (date < date1) {
                           return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                       }
                       return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
                   }];
return sorted;
}
```

if you use sort method than you need to use **[self sortKeyAccordingTodate]** instead **[dictArrData allKeys]**

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Can you provide Swift solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the objects (e.g. Person) by using below code:

NSMutableArray* arrObjects = [NSMutableArray new];

```
for (int i=0;i<12;i++) {
    Person* p1 = [Person new];
    p1.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ABC %d", i+1];
    p1.date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*30*i];
    [arrObjects addObject:p1];
}

// add blank arrays for 12 months
NSMutableArray* matrixObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
    [matrixObjects addObject:[NSMutableArray new]];
}

NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
for (Person* p in arrObjects) {

    int month = (int) [[calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:p.date] month];
    [matrixObjects[month-1] addObject:p];

}

// print resutls
for (int i=0; i<matrixObjects.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Objects in Section %d", i);
    for (Person* p in matrixObjects[i]) {

        NSLog(@"  ROW: %@ %@", p.name, p.date.description);
    }
}
```

Which gives output as below:

```
Objects in Section 0
  ROW: ABC 11 2017-01-29 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 1
  ROW: ABC 12 2017-02-28 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 2
Objects in Section 3
  ROW: ABC 1 2016-04-04 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 4
  ROW: ABC 2 2016-05-04 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 5
  ROW: ABC 3 2016-06-03 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 6
  ROW: ABC 4 2016-07-03 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 7
  ROW: ABC 5 2016-08-02 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 8
  ROW: ABC 6 2016-09-01 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 9
  ROW: ABC 7 2016-10-01 11:55:49 +0000
  ROW: ABC 8 2016-10-31 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 10
  ROW: ABC 9 2016-11-30 11:55:49 +0000
Objects in Section 11
  ROW: ABC 10 2016-12-30 11:55:49 +0000
```

*matrixObjects* is the array of 12 month wise array of you objects, which you can use in *numberOfSections* and *numberOfRows* delegate methods